# How to Use Django File Storage to Share Files Between an API and a Worker

Tags: python, django, api, docker, worker

## Goal

I want to build a local docker compose deployment such that I have 5 services.

- Redis
- Postgres
- RabbitMQ
- Django API
- Django Worker

In this deployment the user uploads a file via the API endpoint. This endpoint will store the file in a `FileField` field in a model.

In a separate transaction the user will trigger an asynchronous task via a separate endpoint. This task will be responsible for

- downloading the file
- extracting the file
- kicking of sub tasks to perform `intermediate processing steps`
- upload the results of the processing to the database

The `intermediate processing steps` are NOT supposed to upload any of the files to the database.

The `intermediate processing steps` are to use django's internal file storage solution to download and upload files there. This is implemented with a file system hierarchy that is not relevant to this question.

## The Problem

I have managed to get my local file system working with this configuration. If I run the backend of `redis`, `postgres`, and `rabbitmq`. And then, I run the API and Worker on my machine locally everything runs fine.

When I create a `docker-compose` configuration and decouple everything. The operation seems to break. And in my docker-compose logging, what I see it:

```
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,626: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,627: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] // BEGINNING TASK
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,627: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,628: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] // Root Job - 183916ca-f6e6-4e7c-a997-e8f516ccf8be
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,628: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] // Parent Job - None
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,628: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] // Current Job - 183916ca-f6e6-4e7c-a997-e8f516ccf8be
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,628: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,629: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] // PERFORMING DATA SET PRE PROCESSING
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,629: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,629: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] {'data_set_id': 1, 'starting_node': 'Live', 'organization_id': 1}
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,630: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Downloading the files required to run!
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,645: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Downloading remote file `organizations/1/data_sets/flow_cytometry/triple_hello_world_payload.tgz`
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,646: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Exists: `False`
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,646: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] ERROR occured: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/api_webserver/media/organizations/1/data_sets/flow_cytometry/triple_hello_world_payload.tgz'.
worker_1  | [2019-10-23 22:27:34,653: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task api.versions.v1.tasks.main_task.main_task[183916ca-f6e6-4e7c-a997-e8f516ccf8be] succeeded in 0.02647909999359399s: {'iteration': 0, 'completion': 0, 'status': 'ERROR', 'message': 'Excecuting `main_task` failed!', 'error': 'Error in `main_task`: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \'/opt/api_webserver/media/organizations/1/data_sets/flow_cytometry/triple_hello_world_payload.tgz\'.'}
```

If I go into the `worker` `docker container` and check the file system the path does NOT exist for the `media` directory and file.
If I go into the `api` `docker container` and check the file system the path does exist for the `media` directory and file.

## Relevant Code

I won't be supplying view code, or api code, as the API works fine.

Upload and file retrieval is handled in the `workers` process by using `django`'s `default_storage` interface.

[Django's Default Storage Interface API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/#the-storage-class)

The issue is related to the worker, so here is some of the related code.

### worker.py

```py
# Python Standard Libraries
import os
# Third-Party Libraries
import tempfile
# Custom
from models.data_set_model import DataSet
from tasks.helpers import download_remote_file


def download_data_set(data_set_id):
    print("Downloading the files required to run!")
    data_set = DataSet.objects.get(id=data_set_id)

    remote_file_path = data_set.file.name
    remote_file_name = os.path.basename(remote_file_path)

    temporary_directory_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temporary_compressed_file_path = os.path.join(temporary_directory_path, remote_file_name)

    download_remote_file(remote_file_path, temporary_compressed_file_path)

    return temporary_compressed_file_path
```

### helpers.py

```py
# Python Standard Libraries
# N/A
# Third-Party Libraries
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
# CustomLibraries
# N/A


def download_remote_file(remote_file_path, local_file_path):
    print(f"Downloading remote file `{remote_file_path}`")
    print(f"Exists: `{default_storage.exists(remote_file_path)}`")
    remote_file_contents = None
    with default_storage.open(remote_file_path) as remote_file_handle:
        print("Reading file contents")
        remote_file_contents = remote_file_handle.read()

    print(f"Placing remote file contents into `{local_file_path}`")
    with open(local_file_path, "wb") as local_file_handle:
        local_file_handle.write(remote_file_contents)
```

## Outstanding Questions

- What am I doing wrong?
- What is the idiomatic way to download files on the worker from the API's FileStorage system?
- Shouldn't the `default_storage.open()` command point to the API's file system and be able to download it

  - If it isn't are there configurations I can make on the worker to support this?
- Does this only work locally because the file system is shared, and the reason this is happening is because `docker-compose` is breaking these into separate environments?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in docker compose, just create a shared docker volume between your api and worker and mount it at a well-known point in both containers, like `/mnt/share`.  Make sure to save the files there in the API and then the worker can access them using the same model since the settings (e.g., `MEDIA_ROOT`) will point both the API and the Worker to `/mnt/share`.